# List<String> : Add and delete?

Tags: java, arrays, list

Got a little question.

I got a List String in my IRC bot:

```
public List<String> Moderatoren = "name1, name2";
```

and i know i can add new names to it by i.e

```
Moderatoren.add(stringContainsAname);
```

so is there actually a way to delete it by the same String contains a name on the list?
i.e:

```
String stringTest = "name1";
```

how can i tell the list to remove only stringTest (name3) from the list?

Comment: Have you read through the `List` javadoc?

Comment: Are you sure that you have your List defined like that: public List<String> Moderatoren = "name1, name2"?

Comment: try this `List<String> moderatoren = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: Ref. [List.remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object))

Comment: It wont compile,you cannot asign String to List

Comment: Well actually no :P i just tried to example what the list contains :p

Comment: It sounds like a List is not really the container you're looking for. Try having a look at Sets.

Answer (score 2):

As one can read in [javadoc of ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
public boolean remove(Object o)
```

> **Removes the first occurrence of the specified element** from this list, if it is present. If the list does not contain the element, it is unchanged. More formally, removes the element with the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))) (if such an element exists). Returns true if this list contained the specified element (or equivalently, if this list changed as a result of the call).